# Is there simple any way to apply a "CSS Style Comparision" of a same area in html?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, dom, stylesheet

I am encountering one problem and it is this: I am having a different size of the same area in my asp.net page after a post-back. So I believe for some reason the style applied to that area changes, most likely.

And this made me to think if there is a way or a tool to compare 2 parts of a web page in terms of styling by highlighting the style property differences?

Something like a CSS comparison.

Is there a way to achieve such a thing?

thanks

Comment: You should just use an inspection tool such as Firebug, and *look* at the styles that are being applied in both instances.

Comment: What I am looking for is to have a kind of tool that does this automatically so that I don't have to walk-through the files and take a risk of skipping some differences by mistake.

Comment: What you do you mean "walk-through the files"? You said that you're having a "different size .. after a post-back". So, use Firebug and look at the styles being applied before and after. You're probably just missing a class being applied.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to inspect the styles and then perhaps use a [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) tool to compare them.

Comment: Ok. But then I have to walk through manually to compare. Is there an add-in for having a style comparison report?

Comment: is there a way to get Firebug’s report on an element’s styles out of it in text form? Cos you’d need that to feed into the diff tool.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite Yes, I just copy pasted the Stack Overflow logo's styles in Notepad.